# How can extract content from a field to multiple new fields with BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I use BigQuery and need to do the following in a SELECT query calling the columns `Id` and `Historical UTMs`.

I have a table with thousands of records with the following pattern as an example:

| Id | Historical UTMs |
| --- | --- |
| 2991501 | WebVisit,2021-04-15 15:11:40,,,email,,,routing,,www.example.com/sh-gc-2021-03-gc-spr-ds-launch-webinar/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=ArticleLeft-button&utm_channel=social&uid=webinarlink&cta=yes&utm_adgroup=Ad Fall 2020&utm_source=instagram&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=SH: NL - Apr; |
| 3004359 | Recent,2021-04-15 20:55:01,UnpaidEarned,marketo,Referral,OC: WE - 2021-04-08 Webinar,O,,,,;Acquisition,2021-04-15 20:55:00,UnpaidEarned,,email,OC: WE - 2021-04-08 Webinar,O,,,,; |
| 3133534 | WebVisit,2021-04-15 18:27:40,,linkedin,post,,,,,www.example.com/solutions/events/ghg-reduction/$query:utm_source=Linkedin&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=SH-WE-2021-04-07-Korean_SPR_Webinar/;First,2021-04-15 14:43:34,,,,,,,,www.example.com/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=logo&uid=Stormgeo&cta=no&utm_source=newsstand21&utm_medium=emailtest&utm_campaign=SH: NL - Apr 2021&utm_term=&utm_content=Article Heading&mkt_tok=MzI4LUj; |

And I want to convert those fields to the following table:

| Id | utm_Type | utm_Timestamp | utm_Channel | utm_Source | utm_Medium | utm_Campaign | utm_Content | utm_Term | utm_Adgroup | utm_Web Page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2991501 | WebVisit | 2021-04-15 15:11:40 | social | instagram | email | SH: NL - Apr |  | routing | Ad Fall 2020 | [www.example.com/sh-gc-2021-03-gc-spr-ds-launch-webinar/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=ArticleLeft-button&utm_channel=social&uid=webinarlink&cta=yes&utm_adgroup=Ad](http://www.example.com/sh-gc-2021-03-gc-spr-ds-launch-webinar/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=ArticleLeft-button&utm_channel=social&uid=webinarlink&cta=yes&utm_adgroup=Ad) Fall 2020&utm_source=instagram&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=SH: NL - Apr |
| 3004359 | Recent | 2021-04-15 20:55:01 | UnpaidEarned | marketo | Referral | OC: WE - 2021-04-08 Webinar: O |  |  |  |  |
| 3004359 | Acquisition | 2021-04-15 20:55:00 | UnpaidEarned |  | email | OC: WE - 2021-04-08 Webinar: O |  |  |  |  |
| 3133534 | WebVisit | 2021-04-15 18:27:40 |  | linkedin | article | SH-WE-2021-04-07-Korean_SPR_Webinar |  |  |  | [www.example.com/solutions/events/ghg-reduction/$query:utm_source=Linkedin&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=SH-WE-2021-04-07-Korean_SPR_Webinar/](http://www.example.com/solutions/events/ghg-reduction/$query:utm_source=Linkedin&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=SH-WE-2021-04-07-Korean_SPR_Webinar/) |
| 3133534 | First | 2021-04-15 14:43:34 |  | newsstand21 | emailtest | SH: NL - Apr 2021 | Article Heading |  |  | [www.example.com/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=logo&uid=Stormgeo&cta=no&utm_source=newsstand21&utm_medium=emailtest&utm_campaign=SH](http://www.example.com/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=logo&uid=Stormgeo&cta=no&utm_source=newsstand21&utm_medium=emailtest&utm_campaign=SH): NL - Apr 2021&utm_term=&utm_content=Article Heading&mkt_tok=MzI4LUj |

1. If the "Historical UTMs" contains multiple records (delimited by ;), then there should be a new row with the same Id.
2. For each of the new fields, the information directly after for example "utm_source=" in the web page url should be added to the correct field if it exist.
3. The delimiters for each new field are commas (,).
4. If a field already has information in it, and this is different from the utm tag, the information in the utm tag in the web page url should "win".

UPDATE #1:

Based on the comments, I have come a lot further. I have now managed to split the content into different columns:

```
SELECT
    Lead.Id, 
    split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(0)] as utm_Type,
    split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(1)] as utm_Timestamp,
    regexp_extract(split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_source=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Source,
    regexp_extract(split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_medium=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Medium,
    regexp_extract(split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_campaign=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Campaign,
    regexp_extract(split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_content=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Content,
    regexp_extract(split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_adgroup=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Adgroup,
    regexp_extract(split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_term=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Term,
    regexp_extract(split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_channel=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Channel,
    split(Lead.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(7)] as utm_Term
FROM
    `dataset.GS_UTMs` AS Lead
WHERE
    Lead.Historical_UTMs  <> ''
```

The last action now, that I still have problems with, is to use the suggested UNNEST to split these into separate rows, keeping the correct ID as the first field in each row. Should I use the UNNEST before or after doing the split? How do I keep the correct Id field for each of the rows?

UPDATE #2:

Now I think it works as intended, except for that it seems to create duplicates of all the new rows. Is there anyone that can help me with this last part? I use the following code:

```
with Expanded as (
  select 
    Lead.Id,
    Lead.Historical_UTMs
  from
    `dataset.GS_UTMs` AS Lead,
    unnest(split(Historical_UTMs,';')) AS Hist_UTMs
)

select
  Expanded.Id,
  split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(0)] as utm_Type,
  split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(1)] as utm_Timestamp,

  CASE
    WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_source=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL
    THEN (split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(2)])  
    ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_source=(.*?)[&;]')
  END AS utm_Source,

  CASE
    WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_medium=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL
    THEN (split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(3)])  
    ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_medium=(.*?)[&;]')
  END AS utm_Medium,

  CASE
    WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_campaign=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL 
    THEN (
       CASE 
       WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'eid=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL
       THEN (split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(4)])  
       ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'eid=(.*?)[&;]')
       END)
    ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_campaign=(.*?)[&;]')
  END AS utm_Campaign,

  CASE
    WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_content=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL
    THEN (split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(5)])  
    ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_content=(.*?)[&;]')
  END AS utm_Content,

  CASE
    WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_adgroup=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL
    THEN (split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(6)])  
    ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_adgroup=(.*?)[&;]')
  END AS utm_Adgroup,

  CASE
    WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_term=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL
    THEN (split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(7)])  
    ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_term=(.*?)[&;]')
  END AS utm_Term,

  CASE
    WHEN regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_channel=(.*?)[&;]') IS NULL
    THEN (split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(7)])  
    ELSE regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'utm_channel=(.*?)[&;]')
  END AS utm_Channel,

  split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)] as utm_Web_Page,
  split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(10)] as utm_Referrer,

  regexp_extract(split(Expanded.Historical_UTMs,',')[safe_offset(9)], r'eid=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Eid,
from
  Expanded
```

Comment: please add text version instead of images so we can use it to help you!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thanks for the input. I have now updated with text versions of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Below should give you an idea of how to approach such cases

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 2991501 id, 'WebVisit,2021-04-15 15:11:40,,,email,,,routing,,www.example.com/sh-gc-2021-03-gc-spr-ds-launch-webinar/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=ArticleLeft-button&utm_channel=social&uid=webinarlink&cta=yes&utm_adgroup=Ad Fall 2020&utm_source=instagram&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=SH: NL - Apr;' UTMs union all
  select 3133534, 'WebVisit,2021-04-15 18:27:40,,linkedin,post,,,,,www.example.com/solutions/events/ghg-reduction/$query:utm_source=Linkedin&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=SH-WE-2021-04-07-Korean_SPR_Webinar/;First,2021-04-15 14:43:34,,,,,,,,www.example.com/$query:eid=NL-2021-04&gid=logo&uid=Stormgeo&cta=no&utm_source=newsstand21&utm_medium=emailtest&utm_campaign=SH: NL - Apr 2021&utm_term=&utm_content=Article Heading&mkt_tok=MzI4LUj;' 
)
select id, 
  split(UTMs)[offset(0)] as utm_Type,
    split(UTMs)[offset(1)] as utm_Timestamp,
  regexp_extract(split(UTMs)[offset(9)], r'utm_source=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Source,
  split(UTMs)[offset(4)] as utm_Medium,
  regexp_extract(split(UTMs)[offset(9)], r'utm_campaign=(.*?)[&;]') as utm_Campaign,
  split(UTMs)[offset(7)] as utm_Term
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

Comment: With «Historical UTMs» field sometimes including hundreds of records delimited by ; how will I split each of these records into new rows, all keeping the id in the original row? Would I use some type of «For» or «While» statements?

Comment: you can use split(..., ';') to create array with those "records delimited by ;" and then use unnest() to "spread" those records into separate rows.

Comment: I now have managed to split the content into different collumns, but still struggle to use the suggested UNNEST to split the Id + the new collumns into separate rows.

Comment: while solution might be quite easy (which I strongly believe so) - your example is overly bushy. I suggest you to 1) heavily simplify your sample as well as focus on specific issue at a time - and 2) post new question - so it will have more chances to be answered. Just suggestion.